# Use a class for my alertbox delegate?

Tags: ios, delegates

I have few viewControllers who use some alertbox, instead of having a delegate in every controller, i would like to create a class like "alertboxDelegate" for that, and link all my alertview to this delegate.

How can i do that?
Thank you

Comment: SharedInstance/Singleton?

Comment: How to link in interface builder to my delegate? do i need to create an external object? do i need to link to my file owner and then do something programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you use your alert views for, it probably doesn't make sense to put all the delegate behavior for the whole app in a single class. Before you do this, you should make sure you're following [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If you're sure you want to, you'd need to define a class and have it implement `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

```
// AlertViewDelegate.h
@interface AlertViewDelegate <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

// AlertViewDelegate.m
@implementation AlertViewDelegate

@end
```

In your view controller where you're presenting an alert view, you'll need to create an instance of this class, but it also has to be retained. The alert view itself won't do this, since delegates are weak references. You can use [Objective-C associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to retain it, which will cause the delegate to be released when the alert view itself is released.

```
- (void)presentAlert
{
    AlertViewDelegate delegate = [[AlertViewDelegate alloc] init];
    UIAlertView *alert = [UIAlertView ...];
    alert.delegate = delegate;
    objc_setAssociatedObject(alert, "RetainedDelegate", delegate, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    [alert show];
}
```

I would strongly recommend against using this pattern, though, and implementing the delegate in the presenting view controller.